# Creating a Month Bucket from Query Result

Tags: sql, sorting, group-by

I have the following query result:

[image]

But I want to group the results by number, and categorize the quantity by month, so the resulting output would be:

[image]

How can I create a month bucket to pick up the date and make it a column and place the values accordingly. Here is my attempt so far:

```
select converT(varchar,year(NewShipDate)) + 'M' + MonthBucket,
        *
from(

select ItemNumber, des.[Product Family], ItemDescription, des.Country, month(RequestedShipDate) as 'Month', ItemOrderedQuantity
from FS_COLine co
join FS_Item it on co.ItemKey = it.ItemKey
left outer join FIN_PLANCAP_2..ProductDescriptions des on it.ItemNumber collate database_default = des.RICNum
where RequestedShipDate >= convert(datetime, '01/01/2016', 120) and
      RequestedShipDate <= convert(datetime, '12/31/2016', 120) and
    isNumeric(it.ItemNumber) = 1 and 
    isNumeric(des.RICNum) = 1 
   --and it.ItemNumber = 35191305
group by ItemNumber, des.[Product Family], ItemDescription, des.Country, month(RequestedShipDate), ItemOrderedQuantity
order by ItemNumber
)A
```

Comment: what is your RDBMS? And have you check pivot?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server. I have not checked pivot, I don't think I am familiar with that. @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: Check it [HERE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) and you will find several example searching for `pivot`.